# How can I change the ComboBox "selectedIndex" on WebBrowser on Silverlight for Windows Phone?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, combobox, browser, selectedindex

In the WebBrowser there is this page (http://gttweb.5t.torino.it/gtt/en/percorsi/percorsi-ricerca.jsp) and there is the "destinationCity" `ComboBox`. In VB.NET I use:

```
Dim DestinationComboBox As HtmlElement = MainWebBrowser.Document.All.Item("destinationCity")
DestinationComboBox.SetAttribute("selectedindex", 1)
```

to change the ComboBox selectedIndex, but in Silverlight (in this `WebBrowser`) there's only the `InvokeScript` function.. How can I change the selectedIndex using `InvokeScript()`?
I've tried

```
InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('destinationCity').selectedindex = 4")
```

But it doesn't work.. Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Chrome Developer Tools, or FireBug to execute the following JavaScript against the given page, you will find that it does not work in a desktop browser:

```
document.getElementById('destinationCity').selectedindex = 4
```

JavaScript, and the `selectedIndex` property are case sensitive. The following works:

```
document.getElementById('destinationCity').selectedIndex = 4
```

Comment: What is the difference between your two examples? And how can I let the code works in my app?

Comment: Solved, I used "selectedIndex", instead of "selectedindex" and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot! (Maybe you have to correct your answer)